# Creat isoline around spatial data points

Tags: r, ggplot2, spatial

I have the following issue. I want to create isolines around spatial points in Europe which represent airports. Around all the data points, I want to create Isolines that represent the Emissions for the flights. The departure of all flights is Zurich and the arrival is around Europe.

```
df <- data.frame(flight_number = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), 
                 dep_lon = c(8.548056,8.548056,8.548056,8.548056,8.548056,8.548056,8.548056),
                 dep_lat = c(47.45806,47.45806,47.45806,47.45806,47.45806,47.45806,47.45806),
                 arr_lon = c(11.548056,16.569700,13.548056, 27.825100, 16.569700,11.569700,19.569700),
                 arr_lat = c(47.45806,48.11030,47.45806,43.23210,48.11030,44.45806,49.45806), 
                 EMISSIONS_KGCO2EQ = c(100,200,300,400,1000,400,200))

ggplot()+
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = dep_lon, y = dep_lat), col = "red")+
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = arr_lon, y = arr_lat), col = "blue")+
  geom_contour(data = df, aes(x = arr_lon, y = arr_lat, z= EMISSIONS_KGCO2EQ))
```

I used this code to plot the points for departure in Zurich and arrival. I want isolines for the "EMISSIONS_KGCO2EQ" for each flight. But what I get is the following error message:

```
Warning messages:
1: stat_contour(): Zero contours were generated 
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I don't get the error message as there are no. Inf values or calculations where its divided by 0.

What I want is Isolines where the emissions is 0 for Zurich and growing according to the values for each flight with an Isoline for each emissions- value.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You don't really have enough information to create isolines here. All you have is two points per flight. The majority of the emissions will occur along the path of the flight, which you don't have, and the rate at which the CO2 emission density falls away from the flight path isn't known (nor, I'm guessing is it realistic to assume a linear, circumferential fall off). Or do I completely misunderstand what you are trying to do? Perhaps a sketch of the expected output would be helpful?

Comment: I added a sketch of what it is supposed to look like @AllanCameron. You are right the assumption that Emissions are not linear but the idea is to show how far you get with a flight with a certain amount of kgCO2 emitted.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for `geom_contour` is says that the x and y values should be a regular grid. So you need to interpolate a regular grid and use that for your contours.  Here is one way of doing it...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(interp)

interpolated <- interp(df$arr_lon, df$arr_lat, df$EMISSIONS_KGCO2EQ, 
                       duplicate = "mean",    #you have duplicated values
                       output = "grid")

#convert this to a long form dataframe
interp_df <- expand_grid(i = seq_along(interpolated$x), 
                         j = seq_along(interpolated$y)) %>% 
  mutate(lon = interpolated$x[i],
         lat = interpolated$y[j],
         emissions = map2_dbl(i, j, ~interpolated$z[.x,.y])) %>% 
  select(-i, -j)

#then you can use this in your plot
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = dep_lon, y = dep_lat), col = "red") +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = arr_lon, y = arr_lat), col = "blue") +
  geom_contour(data = interp_df, aes(x = lon, y = lat, z = emissions))
```

It still doesn't look great with this small dataset, but hopefully you have more than this in your actual data!  You will also need to decide how you want to treat duplicates.